# How to install node on Windows using cmd excluding npm feature?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

I need an older version of npm(3.10.10)  but I need an newer version of nodejs(8.11.3). How can I write a command on Windows Terminal using nvm, for example:  nvm install node@8.11.3 (but exclude npm - do not install npm)?

Answer (score 0):

With nvm at the moment it is not possible.

There is another tool (for windows) https://github.com/nullivex/nodist, which I understand meets what you need.